# How to prevent Google Chrome from saving passwords in ASP.NET MVC 4 after pressing submit button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome-extension

Good Day
Hi i have developed a small log in screen in MVC whenever i press submit button it always offers me whether 
do you want to save password 
i want to disable that option 
i can disable that setting from browser 
Is it possible to do it using java script or through c#
i tried to set the text box property auto complete=off but it does not work it is still saving password
i even tired to set the property of form tag to auto complete=off
but even that does not work

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "Login_txtType", @maxlength = "50", autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: thank you for replying but it does not work it is remembering the password  when click save password is there any way to avoid that offer whether you want to save password

Comment: @suraj..i think there will be problem somewhere else..autocomplete = off works..i used it many times..

Comment: after clicking the submit button browser will ask do u want to remember password if u say yes then again when u log in it will automatically show the password in the text box as soon as you type the user name

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Login", autocomplete = "off" }))

Comment: @suraj...okk okk now i understand your question..that dialog for remember password is inbuilt with the browser you cannot avoid that dialog...

Comment: if i cannot is there any alternative like using jquery when we type first letter password in coming automatically can we clear that on key press or some other event i tried that but it does not work

Comment: @Exception are you there

Comment: @suraj..yes..whatever i know i just told...you just try to google ..

Comment: ok :) have a nice day

Comment: @suraj...have a nice day!!!...

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of HTML5, and according to that standard you can add `autocomplete='off'` to the form tag then `autocomplete='off'` will be applied to all fields within the form.

Example :-

```
<form id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```